# Netty - using the same channelFactory cause only 3 responses to be handled

Tags: httpclient, netty, nio, channelfactory

I was assigned to create an HTTP client based on Netty, but I'm having some difficulties and I hoped there an answer for me.

Well, to use NIO to its full advantage I wanted to use the same channelFactory, meaning all connections are handled by the same boss thread and assigned to the same worker thread pool.

The problem I'm having is that if I use 3 workers I only get 3 operations and then the process is stuck. It seems as if the worker thread is not being released for its next assignment even though I closed the channel after processing response...

Here is how I defined my static channelFactory which I assign later to a bootstrap:

```
static NioClientSocketChannelFactory channelFactory =  new NioClientSocketChannelFactory(
          Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1),
          Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

found the reason - I should have used newCachedThreadPool  and construct the channelFactory using the second Constructor  which includes the #Workers.

netty needs a cachedPool ,otherwise it can't reuse the WI